# Ruby (on Rails) supports for Web service composition and OWLS?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, web-services, rdf, owl

I'm working on a project that uses RoR to generate composition of (RESTful) Web services based on action sequences produced by a external program. Is there a way for RoR to find and invoke available Web services using OWLS or other semantic technologies? How are the supports for OWLS in RoR. I can only find library like ActiveRDF, but not for OWLS. Any suggestions are appreciated.

Comment: Im no newbee to webdevelopment but Ive never heard about OWLS, just found OWL-S using google => http://www.w3.org/Submission/OWL-S/ can you specify what and why you need it. Maybe I can help you then

Comment: I need to add semantic to some Web services so that my RoR app can find them automatically and provide a composition of these services. Any suggestions?

Answer (score 4):

No, there is not. Composition of WebServices using OWL-S is not really pragmatic and there is no real use cases for such technology. 99.999% of the time you are better off gluing those services manually.

OWL-S and WebService composition with ontologies is simply something that has only been tried under EU funded research projects. And, believe me, OWL-S is going nowhere. I did try those things few years ago while doing my PhD and all the stuff around it is very cranky and buggy. If you happen to find something that works, which I doubt it, you will only find it in Java.

Comment: What you said is exactly the situation I come across. Maybe I should do a one-to-one mapping between actions generated by the above mentioned external program and the Web services.